# Mobile first server 7.1 - Issue with Android Devices when send multiple push notifications only last message is received in Notification center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When I send multiple notifications to Apple or Android devices through MFP, Apple devices will receive all the notifications on the other hand Android will only receive the last notification. We are using Unicast Notification to send messages to user devices using this [REST API](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_bulk_messages_post.html).

Comment: Please always mention which MFP release you are using.

Comment: Also, I guess you are actually referring to the "Notification Center" in Android...? If not, please be clearer in your question.

Comment: Yes I ment Notification Center. I have Update the Question.

Comment: I hope you are referring to the case of only the last received notification being visible in the notification shade and not any loss of received notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices will also receive all the push notifications sent by the MFP server. The notification shade ( center) will however display only the last received. This does not mean the earlier ones are lost. They are all still available, just not visible in the notification shade.

You have not mentioned the complete build version of your MFP. To see all the notifications in the shade-

install the latest ifix from FixCentral, rebuild your application. Edit your wlclient.properties and add the following property-

```
showAllNotificationsInTray=true
```

Comment: MFP version I am using is 7.1.0.00.20151130-1648. For this version do I need to install latest ifix?

Comment: That should have the fix. Enable the property in your client application, redeploy the application to device and test.
You should see all the notifications

Comment: Thanks Vivin. This solution works for Samsung Device, but I still see issue with Google Nexus. Not sure if this has to do with device setting.

Comment: Also whenever I make the change in wlclient.properties it gets over written once I do the Android build, basically it removes that property from wlclient.properties. How can prevent this? am I suppose to make change in some file under common dir?

Comment: The property has to be in wlclient.properties. Currently it gets overwritten on a rebuild . This should go away in future.

Comment: Interesting that it did not work on Nexus. It could be a setting issue, but I will verify.

Comment: I recently upgraded to 7.1.0.00.20151227-1725 after that this Push notification fix for multiple messages is no longer working.