# MobileFirst 7.1 - Issue with multiple Push Notification for Android devices after upgrade to MFP 7.1.0.00.20151227-1725

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When I send multiple notifications to Apple or Android devices through MFP, Apple devices will display all notifications in the notifications center on the other hand Android will only display one last notification. We are using Unicast Notification to send messages to user devices using this [REST API](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_bulk_messages_post.html).

Initially my issue got fixed when I implemented solution given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617678/mobile-first-server-7-1-issue-with-android-devices-when-send-multiple-push-not).

But after upgrading to MFP 7.1.0.00.20151227-1725 I started facing the issue again.

Comment: So your problem is not with "receiving", but with "displaying notifications on the notifications center". You need to precise in you question.

Comment: Did you rebuild your application and lose the new attribute you had added earlier?

Comment: Though rebuild removes the attribute I always add the attribute back before deploying the app on Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

It it a known limitation that the attribute gets removed from the file upon re-build, since a re-build re-generates the file...

You need to add it back after a re-build. It is scheduled to be enhanced in the future so this won't be needed.

For now you can use for example an Ant task to replace the wlclient.properties file post-build with a version that contains again the attribute.

Comment: Even after doing that issue remains the same.